# Author data not coming up in Google search

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, rich-snippets

I was trying to add author information for search. I followed [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?hl=en) link and did everything in option 2. Added `?rel=author` and added my blog in my Google+ account. But even after re submitting for index from Google webmasters author info doesnt come up. I have tested this through the Rich snippet testing tool in Webmasters account and everything seems fine and I do see a dummy result showing full info. And it also says *rel=author markup has successfully established*

So what am I missing out here ?

EDIT:
Ok after long time it did come up in search results last week, but now its not coming up ? Is it related to traffic to site(which is not too bad) ?

Comment: How long has it been? Did you see this in that link: `Google doesn't guarantee to show author information in Google Web Search`

Comment: @dan Its been almost 3 days now. Yes I *did* notice that peice of warning so am asking what else needs to be done to get authorship info in search results ?

Comment: If it works with the testing tool, then you'll need to wait a bit longer...it can take weeks for things to show up in Google.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Google....

> **Rich snippets not appearing**
>
> **Have you only recently updated your content?**
>
> If you've marked up your site's content, tested your markup using the
>   rich snippets testing tool, and checked the common issues above,
>   remember that it takes time for rich snippets to appear in search. You
>   can also let us know about your content. (Although Google won't be
>   able to individually reply to your message, we may use the information
>   you supply to improve our detection and display of information in
>   search results.)

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493